# ASP.NET Core: programatically set the resource file for localized view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, localization

I have web app written in ASP.NET Core v2.1. The app uses localized views configured via `LocalizationOptions.ResourcesPath = "Resources"` and the access to localized strings is via injected `IViewLocalizer` in cshtml files.

In some conditions I'd like to render the view with the different resource file than the default one located in `Resources` folder. The other resource file have the same keys as the default one (no need to change the view) so only the different texts will be rendered.

E.g. consider such action method in controller and see the comments what I'd like to solve:

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> ShowSomething([FromQuery] bool useDifferentResource)
{
    if (useDifferentResource)
    {
        // how to render the view which will use different resource file
        // then the default found in Resources folder?
        // return View("MyView");
    }
    
    // this renders the view with the default resource file found in Resources folder
    return View("MyView");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly I'm not so sure about the necessity of your requirement. But by digging into the source code, I've found it possible and come up with a solution here.

Actually the `IViewLocalizer` is instantiated by `IHtmlLocalizerFactory` which is registered as a singleton. That depends on `IStringLocalizerFactory` which is also registered as a singleton. Here we use localization by resources file (managed by `ResourceManager`) so the implementation class is `ResourceManagerStringLocalizerFactory`.
That factory consumes the options `LocalizationOptions` to get the configured `ResourcesPath` used for creating the instance of `IStringLocalizer` which is wrapped by `HtmlLocalizer` and finally wrapped in `ViewLocalizer`. The point here is the result is cached by a cache key depending on the view/page path & the name of the assembly (in which the resources are embedded). So right after first time creating the instance of `ViewLocalizer` (available via DI), it will be cached and you have no chance to change the configured `ResourcesPath` or intercept to change it somehow.

That means we need a custom `ResourceManagerStringLocalizerFactory` to override the `Create` method (actually it's not virtual, but we can re-implement it). We need to include one more factor (the runtime resources path) to the cache key so that caching will work correctly. Also there is one virtual method in `ResourceManagerStringLocalizerFactory` that can be overridden to provide your runtime resources path: `GetResourceLocationAttribute`. To minimize the implementation code for the custom `ResourceManagerStringLocalizerFactory`, I choose that method to override. By reading the source code, you can see that it's not the only point to intercept to provide your own runtime resources path but it seems to be the easiest.

That's the core principle. However when it comes to the implementation for the full solution, it's not that simple. Here's the full code:

```
/// <summary>
/// A ViewLocalizer that can be aware of the request feature IActiveViewLocalizerFeature to use instead of 
/// basing on the default implementation of ViewLocalizer
/// </summary>
public class ActiveLocalizerAwareViewLocalizer : ViewLocalizer
{
    readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
    public ActiveLocalizerAwareViewLocalizer(IHtmlLocalizerFactory localizerFactory, IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment,
        IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor) : base(localizerFactory, hostingEnvironment)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    public override LocalizedHtmlString this[string key, params object[] arguments]
    {
        get
        {
            var localizer = _getActiveLocalizer();
            return localizer == null ? base[key, arguments] : localizer[key, arguments];
        }
    }

    public override LocalizedHtmlString this[string key]
    {
        get
        {
            var localizer = _getActiveLocalizer();
            return localizer == null ? base[key] : localizer[key];
        }
    }
    IHtmlLocalizer _getActiveLocalizer()
    {
        return _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Features.Get<IActiveViewLocalizerFeature>()?.ViewLocalizer;
    }
}

public static class HtmlLocalizerFactoryWithRuntimeResourcesPathExtensions
{
    public static T WithResourcesPath<T>(this T factory, string resourcesPath) where T : IHtmlLocalizerFactory
    {
        if (factory is IRuntimeResourcesPath overridableFactory)
        {
            overridableFactory.SetRuntimeResourcesPath(resourcesPath);
        }
        return factory;
    }
}

public interface IActiveViewLocalizerFeature
{
    IHtmlLocalizer ViewLocalizer { get; }
}

public class ActiveViewLocalizerFeature : IActiveViewLocalizerFeature
{
    public ActiveViewLocalizerFeature(IHtmlLocalizer viewLocalizer)
    {
        ViewLocalizer = viewLocalizer;
    }
    public IHtmlLocalizer ViewLocalizer { get; }
}

public interface IRuntimeResourcesPath
{
    string ResourcesPath { get; }
    void SetRuntimeResourcesPath(string resourcesPath);
}

public class RuntimeResourcesPathHtmlLocalizerFactory : HtmlLocalizerFactory, IRuntimeResourcesPath
{
    readonly IStringLocalizerFactory _stringLocalizerFactory;
    public RuntimeResourcesPathHtmlLocalizerFactory(IStringLocalizerFactory localizerFactory) : base(localizerFactory)
    {
        _stringLocalizerFactory = localizerFactory;
    }
    //NOTE: the factory is registered as a singleton, so we need this to manage different resource paths used on different tasks
    readonly AsyncLocal<string> _asyncResourcePath = new AsyncLocal<string>();
    public string ResourcesPath => _asyncResourcePath.Value;

    void IRuntimeResourcesPath.SetRuntimeResourcesPath(string resourcesPath)
    {
        _asyncResourcePath.Value = resourcesPath;
    }
    public override IHtmlLocalizer Create(string baseName, string location)
    {
        if (_stringLocalizerFactory is IRuntimeResourcesPath overridableFactory)
        {
            overridableFactory.SetRuntimeResourcesPath(ResourcesPath);
        }
        return base.Create(baseName, location);
    }
}

public static class RuntimeResourcesPathHtmlLocalizerFactoryExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates an IHtmlLocalizer with a runtime resources path (instead of using the configured ResourcesPath)
    /// </summary>
    public static IHtmlLocalizer CreateWithResourcesPath(this IHtmlLocalizerFactory factory, string resourcesPath, string baseName, string location = null)
    {
        location = location ?? Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Name;
        var result = factory.WithResourcesPath(resourcesPath).Create(baseName, location);
        factory.WithResourcesPath(null);
        return result;
    }
}

public static class RuntimeResourcesPathLocalizationExtensions
{
    static IHtmlLocalizer _useLocalizer(ActionContext actionContext, string resourcesPath, string viewPath)
    {
        var factory = actionContext.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IHtmlLocalizerFactory>();

        viewPath = viewPath.Substring(0, viewPath.Length - Path.GetExtension(viewPath).Length).TrimStart('/', '\\')
                   .Replace("/", ".").Replace("\\", ".");

        var location = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Name;

        var localizer = factory.CreateWithResourcesPath(resourcesPath, viewPath, location);
        actionContext.HttpContext.Features.Set<IActiveViewLocalizerFeature>(new ActiveViewLocalizerFeature(localizer));
        return localizer;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Can be used inside Controller
    /// </summary>
    public static IHtmlLocalizer UseLocalizer(this ActionContext actionContext, string resourcesPath, string viewOrPageName = null)
    {
        //find the view before getting the path
        var razorViewEngine = actionContext.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IRazorViewEngine>();
        if (actionContext is ControllerContext cc)
        {
            viewOrPageName = viewOrPageName ?? cc.ActionDescriptor.ActionName;
            var viewResult = razorViewEngine.FindView(actionContext, viewOrPageName, false);
            return _useLocalizer(actionContext, resourcesPath, viewResult.View.Path);
        }
        var pageResult = razorViewEngine.FindPage(actionContext, viewOrPageName);
        //NOTE: here we have pageResult.Page is an IRazorPage but we don't use that to call UseLocalizer
        //because that IRazorPage instance has very less info (lacking ViewContext, PageContext ...)
        //The only precious info we have here is the Page.Path
        return _useLocalizer(actionContext, resourcesPath, pageResult.Page.Path);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Can be used inside Razor View or Razor Page
    /// </summary>
    public static IHtmlLocalizer UseLocalizer(this IRazorPage razorPage, string resourcesPath)
    {
        var path = razorPage.ViewContext.ExecutingFilePath;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(path))
        {
            path = razorPage.ViewContext.View.Path;
        }
        if (path == null) return null;
        return _useLocalizer(razorPage.ViewContext, resourcesPath, path);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Can be used inside PageModel
    /// </summary>
    public static IHtmlLocalizer UseLocalizer(this PageModel pageModel, string resourcesPath)
    {
        return pageModel.PageContext.UseLocalizer(resourcesPath, pageModel.RouteData.Values["page"]?.ToString()?.TrimStart('/'));
    }
}
```

The custom `ResourceManagerStringLocalizerFactory` I've mentioned at the beginning:

```
public class RuntimeResourcesPathResourceManagerStringLocalizerFactory 
    : ResourceManagerStringLocalizerFactory, IRuntimeResourcesPath, IStringLocalizerFactory
{
    readonly AsyncLocal<string> _asyncResourcePath = new AsyncLocal<string>();
    public string ResourcesPath => _asyncResourcePath.Value;
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, ResourceManagerStringLocalizer> _localizerCache =
        new ConcurrentDictionary<string, ResourceManagerStringLocalizer>();

    public RuntimeResourcesPathResourceManagerStringLocalizerFactory(IOptions<LocalizationOptions> localizationOptions, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory) : base(localizationOptions, loggerFactory)
    {
    }
    protected override ResourceLocationAttribute GetResourceLocationAttribute(Assembly assembly)
    {
        //we is where we override the configured ResourcesPath and use the runtime ResourcesPath.
        return ResourcesPath == null ? base.GetResourceLocationAttribute(assembly) : new ResourceLocationAttribute(ResourcesPath);
    }        

    public void SetRuntimeResourcesPath(string resourcesPath)
    {
        _asyncResourcePath.Value = resourcesPath;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Almost cloned from the source code of ResourceManagerStringLocalizerFactory
    /// We need to re-implement this because the framework code caches the result of Create using a cache key depending on only baseName & location.
    /// But here we introduce one more parameter of (runtime) ResourcesPath, so we need to include that in the cache key as well for 
    /// it to work properly (otherwise each time changing the runtime ResourcesPath, the same cached result will be returned, which is wrong).
    /// </summary>        
    IStringLocalizer IStringLocalizerFactory.Create(string baseName, string location)
    {
        if (baseName == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(baseName));
        }

        if (location == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(location));
        }

        return _localizerCache.GetOrAdd($"B={baseName},L={location},R={ResourcesPath}", _ =>
        {
            var assemblyName = new AssemblyName(location);
            var assembly = Assembly.Load(assemblyName);
            baseName = GetResourcePrefix(baseName, location);

            return CreateResourceManagerStringLocalizer(assembly, baseName);
        });
    }
}
```

One more extension class to help register the custom services conveniently:

```
public static class RuntimeResourcesPathLocalizationServiceCollectionExtensions
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddRuntimeResourcesPathForLocalization(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSingleton<IStringLocalizerFactory, RuntimeResourcesPathResourceManagerStringLocalizerFactory>();
        services.AddSingleton<IHtmlLocalizerFactory, RuntimeResourcesPathHtmlLocalizerFactory>();
        return services.AddSingleton<IViewLocalizer, ActiveLocalizerAwareViewLocalizer>();
    }
}
```

We implement a custom `IViewLocalizer` as well so that it can be seamlessly used in your code. Its job is just to check if there is any active instance of `IHtmlLocalizer` shared via the `HttpContext` (as a feature called `IActiveViewLocalizerFeature`. Each different runtime resources path will create a different `IHtmlLocalizer` that will be shared as the active localizer. Usually in one request scope (and in the view context), we usually just need to use one runtime resources path (specified at the very beginning before rendering the view).

To register the custom services:

```
services.AddRuntimeResourcesPathForLocalization();
```

To use the localizer with runtime resources path:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> ShowSomething([FromQuery] bool useDifferentResource)
{
  if (useDifferentResource)
  {
     this.UseLocalizer("resources path of your choice");
  }
    
  return View("MyView");
}
```

**NOTE**: The `UseLocalizer` inside the Controller's or PageModel's scope is not very efficient due to an extra logic to find the view/page (using `IRazorViewEngine` as you can see in the code). So if possible, you should move the `UseLocalizer` to the `RazorPage` or `View` instead. The switching condition can be passed via view-model or any other ways (view data, view bag, ...).

Comment: Could you explain your first sentence, please? _"Firstly I'm not so sure about the necessity of your requirement"_... Is there any other easier solution for my case? Simply I need to display different localized texts in the view based on some business conditions.

Comment: @PetrFelzmann as I understand, localization seems to involve only one argument: *the current culture or language*. So if you have other arguments to control which should be display, especially applied on only part of the view (not the whole), you might need the solution here. Otherwise, such as your *different localized text* is applied on the whole view, then just switch the culture accordingly.

Comment: E.g: usually, you have query string of `lang` to switch the culture, but if you mean you need more complicated business to determine the `lang`, we have simpler solutions, of course the whole view ***will be affected*** by that culture. Here I understand that you have different parts of your view which need to applied with different localization resources (from different paths).

Comment: My problem is not about culture. I'd like to preserve the culture, but just change the texts values for the same resource key.

But why you are not sure about the necessity of my requirement?

Comment: @PetrFelzmann because I don't really understand your ***original requirement***. I just understand what you directly want: ***programmatically set resources path***. And yes, I'd found that interesting and tried to solve it. That's all.